# What is a correct way to display complex models in AR on Android app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

Let's assume I have a complete android app that originally **was not** built for AR.

I want to press the button in this app to turn on the camera and place an ar model into the scene. The model is a human body with a rig. I want the body to deform, physically interact with other models in the scene *(for example some balls)*, and the material to realistically reflect the light.

Should this be done in **Android Studio** somehow or I should build a **Unity** app and then include it as a library to my Android Studio project?

P.S.
I hope the answer is using Unity because it is easy to do rigged models and physics in it. But maybe there are some pitfalls that will appear after using Unity for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can play model animations in ARCore Sceneform with Android native sdk. You can use mixamo for rigged models for example.
HDR environmental lighting from ARCore is supported in both Unity and Android native sdk.
If you want to create  more complex particle effects, you should use Unity. 
It all depends on yours use case.
Speaking from experience, Unity sdk for ARCore is sometimes behind on some features and you might benefit from using native sdk instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does Sceneform supporters physics calculation (for ragdoll)? I have not found any information about that.

Comment: Sceneform does not support physics calculation, you might need to find another library for that